# A qualifying exam problem complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help me with this qualifying exam!! I got stuck on it for quite some time.

If $H$ is the vector space of entire functions $f$ such that $$\int_\mathbb{C}|f(z)|^2\,d\mu(z)<\infty,$$ where $d\mu(z)$ is the measure on $\mathbb{C}$ given by $d\mu(z)=e^{-|z|^2}\,d\nu(z)$, where $d\nu(z)$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove that $H$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(\mathbb{C},d\mu)$.

My thought is that if $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $H$ and $f\in L_2(\mathbb{C},d\mu)$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$, and if we can show that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, then Montel's theorem would imply that a subsequence of $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on compact subsets to an entire function, which would conclude the proof. But I couldn't figure out why $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded, or if this method will work at all. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: If you had Lebesgue measure instead of $\mu$ you could use Montel's Theorem. The Mean Value Property of analytic function would give local boundedness in that case.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I finished the proof by first writing the $\int_{\mathbb{C}}f(z)^2\,d\mu(z)$ in polar coordinates, then use the mean value property for $f(z)^2$.